# Problems with .clone & traverse within (selector).each()

Tags: jquery, clone, each

I have a some markup being output for a number of yoga classes. I'd like to move/copy the instructors photo from one part of the markup (hidden on page load) and place it next to their name, which is visible on page load.

With 3 classes (and 3 instructors) I'm able to place the photos of all 3 instructors into my desired location of the first course. Unfortunately I want the photos from each instructors to be placed into the desired places in their own course only.

You can see what's happening currently here - https://naada.staging.wpengine.com.

I'm successfully cloning the instructor photo in each session, but I am placing them all in one place instead of their respective courses.  What am I not understanding with `(selector).each` or `$(this).closest()`? Thanks!

```js
var instructor = $('div.live-stream-sched healcode-widget .bw-session__details .bw-session__instructor');
instructor.each(function() {
  var photo = $('.bw-session__photo').clone();
  $(this).closest('.bw-session__details').prev().find('.bw-session__group2').prepend(photo);
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="live-stream-sched">
  <!-- First Class -->
  <div class="bw-session">
    <div class="bw-session__basics">
      <div class="bw-session__info">
        <div class="bw-session__time">10:00 AM – 11:30 AM</div>
        <div class="bw-session__group1">LIVEstream Naada Level 2</div>
        <!-- Want to move clone photo here -->
        <div class="bw-session__group2">Kreg Weiss</div>
        <span class="bw-widget__cart_button">Sign Up</span>
      </div>
      <div class="bw-session__details">
        <div class="bw-session__expanded">
          <div class="bw-session__full-title">LIVEstream Naada Level 2 Description</div>
          <div class="bw-session__description">[..]</div>
          <div class="bw-session__instructor" style="">
            <div class="bw-session__photo" style="background-image: url('instructor1.jpg'); "></div>
            <div class="bw-session__instructor-name">Kreg Weiss</div>
            <div class="bw-session__bio">[..]</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Second Class -->
    <div class="bw-session">
      <div class="bw-session__basics">
        <div class="bw-session__info">
          <div class="bw-session__time">12:30 PM – 2:00 PM</div>
          <div class="bw-session__group1">LIVEstream Naada Level 1</div>
          <!-- Want to move clone photo here -->
          <div class="bw-session__group2">Kreg Weiss</div>
          <span class="bw-widget__cart_button">Sign Up</span>
        </div>
        <div class="bw-session__details">
          <div class="bw-session__expanded">
            <div class="bw-session__full-title">LIVEstream Naada Level 1 Description</div>
            <div class="bw-session__description">[..]</div>
            <div class="bw-session__instructor" style="">
              <div class="bw-session__photo" style="background-image: url('instructor1.jpg'); "></div>
              <div class="bw-session__instructor-name">Kreg Weiss</div>
              <div class="bw-session__bio">[..]</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Third Class -->
      <div class="bw-session">
        <div class="bw-session__basics">
          <div class="bw-session__info">
            <div class="bw-session__time">3:30 PM – 5:00 PM</div>
            <div class="bw-session__group1">LIVEstream Yoga for Healthy Aging</div>
            <!-- Want to move clone photo here -->
            <div class="bw-session__group2">Susan Bronson</div>
            <span class="bw-widget__cart_button">Sign Up</span>
          </div>
          <div class="bw-session__details">
            <div class="bw-session__expanded">
              <div class="bw-session__full-title">LIVEstream Naada Level 2 Description</div>
              <div class="bw-session__description">[..]</div>
              <div class="bw-session__instructor" style="">
                <div class="bw-session__photo" style="background-image: url('instructor1.jpg'); "></div>
                <div class="bw-session__instructor-name">Susan Bronson</div>
                <div class="bw-session__bio">[..]</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because you select all the `.bw-session__photo` elements. You need to only select the one related to the current `.bw-session__instructor` in your loop. To do that use `$(this).find()`, like this:

```js
var $instructor = $('div.live-stream-sched .bw-session__details .bw-session__instructor');

$instructor.each(function() {
  var $photo = $(this).find('.bw-session__photo').clone();
  $(this).closest('.bw-session__details').prev().find('.bw-session__group2').prepend($photo);
});
```

```css
.bw-session__photo {
  display: block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #C00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="live-stream-sched">
  <!-- First Class -->
  <div class="bw-session">
    <div class="bw-session__basics">
      <div class="bw-session__info">
        <div class="bw-session__time">10:00 AM – 11:30 AM</div>
        <div class="bw-session__group1">LIVEstream Naada Level 2</div>
        <!-- Want to move clone photo here -->
        <div class="bw-session__group2">Kreg Weiss</div>
        <span class="bw-widget__cart_button">Sign Up</span>
      </div>
      <div class="bw-session__details">
        <div class="bw-session__expanded">
          <div class="bw-session__full-title">LIVEstream Naada Level 2 Description</div>
          <div class="bw-session__description">[..]</div>
          <div class="bw-session__instructor" style="">
            <div class="bw-session__photo" style="background-image: url('instructor1.jpg'); "></div>
            <div class="bw-session__instructor-name">Kreg Weiss</div>
            <div class="bw-session__bio">[..]</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Second Class -->
    <div class="bw-session">
      <div class="bw-session__basics">
        <div class="bw-session__info">
          <div class="bw-session__time">12:30 PM – 2:00 PM</div>
          <div class="bw-session__group1">LIVEstream Naada Level 1</div>
          <!-- Want to move clone photo here -->
          <div class="bw-session__group2">Kreg Weiss</div>
          <span class="bw-widget__cart_button">Sign Up</span>
        </div>
        <div class="bw-session__details">
          <div class="bw-session__expanded">
            <div class="bw-session__full-title">LIVEstream Naada Level 1 Description</div>
            <div class="bw-session__description">[..]</div>
            <div class="bw-session__instructor" style="">
              <div class="bw-session__photo" style="background-image: url('instructor1.jpg'); "></div>
              <div class="bw-session__instructor-name">Kreg Weiss</div>
              <div class="bw-session__bio">[..]</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Third Class -->
      <div class="bw-session">
        <div class="bw-session__basics">
          <div class="bw-session__info">
            <div class="bw-session__time">3:30 PM – 5:00 PM</div>
            <div class="bw-session__group1">LIVEstream Yoga for Healthy Aging</div>
            <!-- Want to move clone photo here -->
            <div class="bw-session__group2">Susan Bronson</div>
            <span class="bw-widget__cart_button">Sign Up</span>
          </div>
          <div class="bw-session__details">
            <div class="bw-session__expanded">
              <div class="bw-session__full-title">LIVEstream Naada Level 2 Description</div>
              <div class="bw-session__description">[..]</div>
              <div class="bw-session__instructor" style="">
                <div class="bw-session__photo" style="background-image: url('instructor1.jpg'); "></div>
                <div class="bw-session__instructor-name">Susan Bronson</div>
                <div class="bw-session__bio">[..]</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm! I believed that if I was inside my `instructor.each(function{..})` then I wouldn't have to specify a single `bw-sessions__photo` because I was already within the .each() loop for that instructor. But `$(This).find()` is required...  I'm thinking like a for_each() PHP loop.